# Need help understanding a simplification in a simultaneous search model.

Tags: statistics, economics, searching

The problem I am trying to solve is $\max_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \int_0^1 u d F(u)^k - ck$, where the associated utility is an iid random variable U following $F(\cdot)$ on [0,1]. $c > 0$ is the constant marginal cost of search. By choosing $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the decision maker knows the realized $u_1, u_2, \ldots , u_k$ and chooses the highest alternative.

The simplification I am having trouble with is at the end of this line of logic:

"Notice that for each k, the benefit of search is given by: $\int_0^1 u d F(u)^k = 1 - \int_0^1 F(u)^k$ du$"

This seems to me to have to be integration by parts I'm just not sure where the 1 is coming from.

Comment: is $F(1)=1$ by any chance?

Comment: Yes by the definition of a CDF on support [a,b], F(a) = 0 and F(b) = 1. We are on support [0,1]. Did I just forget to evaluate?

Comment: yes you did, I think at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0^1 d(uF^k(u)) = \left[uF^k(u)\right]_0^1 =  \int_0^1 u dF^k(u) + \int_0^1 F(u)^k du
$$
this is leads to
$$
\left[uF^k(u)\right]_0^1  = 1\cdot F^k(1) - 0\cdot F^k(0) =  1 = \int_0^1 u dF^k(u) + \int_0^1 F(u)^k du
$$
re-arrange
$$
\int_0^1 u dF^k(u) = 1 - \int_0^1 F(u)^k du
$$

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you know to use that first identity?

Comment: It was integration by parts, then worked it through and wrote it as succinctly as I could.